# Can I write a single file to a storage device without a file system?

Tags: file, unix, filesystems

The way I understood it is that a file system is needed to tell which file is which and therefore one needs to use a file system on almost every storage device. This leads to the question: do I need a file system if I only want to store one file to a storage device?

So lets a assume I have a not formatted device mounted on /dev/sdb and want to create a file containing “Hello World!” and some EOF on this device. Can this be done without a file system?

Comment: Yes, you can copy a file to a raw block device. Accessing a raw block device may require `root`. You have to think about how to mark/detect the end of the file as there will not be an automatic EOF condition except when you have read the whole device.

Comment: Assuming that text is in the file `hello.txt`, command  `dd if=hello.txt of=/dev/sdb` will write its content to disk `/dev/sdb`. Or `echo "Hello World" | dd  of=/dev/sdb`.